# ADA not able to link glut32.dll in GPS IDE

Tags: ada

I'm writing simple OpenGl program using ADA in GPS IDE.

I have all supporting file (like glut.ads/adb, Gl.ads/adb)

I have created Pragma like `"pragma Linker_Options("../Lib/glut32.dll");"`

But I get errors like

```
Link
   [link]         main.adb
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
gprbuild: link of main.adb failed
gprbuild: failed command was: c:\gnat\2019\bin\gcc.exe main.o b__main.o D:\Saravanan\Project\Training\Open_GL Project\obj\GL-Extended.o D:\Saravanan\Project\Training\Open_GL Project\obj\GL.o D:\Saravanan\Project\Training\Open_GL Project\obj\glut.o -LD:\Saravanan\Project\Training\Open_GL Project\obj\ -LD:\Saravanan\Project\Training\Open_GL Project\obj\ -LC:/gnat/2019/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/adalib/ -static-libgcc ../Lib/glut32.dll C:/gnat/2019/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/adalib/libgnat
.a -Wl,--stack=0x2000000 -o main.exe
[2019-12-23 15:28:13] process exited with status 4, elapsed time: 01.83s
```

So kindly help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try

```
pragma Linker_Options("-L../Lib");
pragma Linker_Options("-lglut32");
```

See also, for example, [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/platform_specific_information.html#using-dlls-with-gnat) and [here](http://mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use).

Comment: `c:/gnat/2019/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ..\Lib/glut32.dll when searching for -lglut32
c:/gnat/2019/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ..\Lib\glut32.lib when searching for -lglut32
c:/gnat/2019/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32`

Comment: I think I have dll, which I need to generate .a file am I right?

Comment: It seems that the DLL is incompatible (it's probably a 32-bit version instead of a 64-bit version). You should also already have the `.a` file. If not, then you have to compile it yourself from the GLUT sources (you need to compile it for MinGW). I currently can't explain step-by-step how to do that. You might want to check the source code of [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/). This site [here](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) seems to provide prepacked FreeGLUT binaries for MinGW, but please use these at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using FreeGLUT, you need to link against additional system libraries:

```
pragma Linker_Options ("-lglu32", "-lopengl32", "-lgdi32",
                       "-lwinmm", "-luser32");
```

These are from the [FreeGLUT C header](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/c8d14b13af997a907a9c1c98f3f26b102bb89401/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h#L104).

Then you either do what @DeeDee suggested, or you place your DLL file into `c:\gnat\2019\lib` and just do

```
pragma Linker_Options ("-lglut32");
```

You might want to have a look at my [OpenGLAda](https://github.com/flyx/OpenGLAda) binding which handles this stuff with GPR files but uses GLFW instead of GLUT.