# How to solve "undefined reference to glGetDoublev'" while integration GLUT in ADA ? IDE Used: GPS. Im trying to create a simple window

Tags: opengl, ada

Sample Main Code:(main.adb)

```ada
    with GL;
    with GLUT;
    procedure Main is
       L_window_status : Integer;

    begin
       GLUT.Init;
       L_window_status:= GLUT.CreateWindow(Title => "PAV") ;
    end Main;
```

Console Error Messages:

```
gprbuild -d -PD:\Training\IPM\opengl.gpr
Bind
   [gprbind]      main.bexch
   [Ada]          main.ali
Link
   [link]         main.adb
c:/gnat/2019/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/ld.exe: D:\Training\IPM\obj\GL.o:GL.adb:(.text+0x49a0): undefined reference to `glGetDoublev'
c:/gnat/2019/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-mingw32/8.3.1/ld.exe: D:\Training\IPM\obj\GL.o:GL.adb:(.text+0x49bb): undefined reference to `glGetString'
```

Comment: You need to link with the correct libraries. See, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59453491) related question.

Comment: You should show us your `opengl.gpr` file so that we see how you try to link against OpenGL.